# Find/replace on many words

Tags: c

I have a log input message and I need to format it according to the following:

```
#define DEFAULT_FORMAT "[%(levelname)] %(time) %(name) - %(filename):%(funcName):%(lineno) - %(msg)"
```

If wan to write a function that basically does something like (in pseudo-code):

```
char output_buffer[size??];
char* replacements = {"%(levelname)", "%(time)", ...};
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(replacements)/sizeof(*replacements) ; i++)
    replace(from, to, output_buffer);
```

But this raises a few tricky points, such as, how would I know the size of the output buffer? Would I have to do two-passes, first to see the size of the output buffer and second, to actually to do the replacement? What might be a sensible way to do the above?

Comment: Tip: `NULL` terminate your arrays of strings. It makes iterating super easy, you can do it with one pointer, no index needed, and you don't have to do a clunky calculation with `sizeof` that can fail if your array has decayed to a pointer.

Comment: A two pass approach works. If it's fast enough, sounds good. The alternative is to guess, resize the buffer if necessary, and trim at the end to the proper size. Sometimes a quick scan is faster than doing a lot of allocations.